# DNS not working after reboot

Tags: dns, vpn, openvpn, resolv.conf

After booting the Ubuntu 18.10 I can't resolve domain names and my `/etc/resolv.conf` file is looking like this:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

The `$ nslookup google.com - 127.0.0.53` command is not returning anything either.

This became an issue after installing this script for DNS support in OpenVPN: https://github.com/masterkorp/openvpn-update-resolv-conf

I think I've installed the `openresolv` package, but I'm not sure how to configure everything to work together.

Right now, I just have to manually update the `/etc/resolv.conf` with the Google DNS servers every time after boot. However, the VPN is working fine, so it looks like it's updating the DNS for this.

What could be done to make it work after rebooting the PC and after establishing a VPN tunnel with OpenVPN?

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

---

> Commands requested by @heynnema:

I've run them just after reboot, before connecting to VPN.

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 18.10

$ uname -a
Linux destiny 4.18.0-13-generic #14-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 5 09:04:24 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ ls -al /etc/resolv.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 52 янв 21 21:20 /etc/resolv.conf

$ ps auxc | grep -i dns

$ host 8.8.8.8
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

$ host www.ebay.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

$ ps auxc | grep -i resolv

$ cat /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
cat: /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf: No such file or directory

$ cat /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
cat: /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf: No such file or directory

$ ls -al /etc/openvpn
total 36
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 янв 15 14:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 139 root root 12288 янв 21 23:43 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 сен  3 11:57 client
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 янв 15 14:25 scripts
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 сен  3 11:57 server
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1468 сен  3 11:57 update-resolv-conf
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  2152 янв 15 14:54 update-resolv-conf.sh

# openvpn --version
OpenVPN 2.4.6 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Sep  3 2018
library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018, LZO 2.10
Originally developed by James Yonan
Copyright (C) 2002-2018 OpenVPN Inc <sales@openvpn.net>
Compile time defines: enable_async_push=no enable_comp_stub=no enable_crypto=yes enable_crypto_ofb_cfb=yes enable_debug=yes enable_def_auth=yes enable_dependency_tracking=no enable_dlopen=unknown enable_dlopen_self=unknown enable_dlopen_self_static=unknown enable_fast_install=needless enable_fragment=yes enable_iproute2=yes enable_libtool_lock=yes enable_lz4=yes enable_lzo=yes enable_maintainer_mode=no enable_management=yes enable_multihome=yes enable_pam_dlopen=no enable_pedantic=no enable_pf=yes enable_pkcs11=yes enable_plugin_auth_pam=yes enable_plugin_down_root=yes enable_plugins=yes enable_port_share=yes enable_selinux=no enable_server=yes enable_shared=yes enable_shared_with_static_runtimes=no enable_silent_rules=no enable_small=no enable_static=yes enable_strict=no enable_strict_options=no enable_systemd=yes enable_werror=no enable_win32_dll=yes enable_x509_alt_username=yes with_aix_soname=aix with_crypto_library=openssl with_gnu_ld=yes with_mem_check=no with_sysroot=no
```

---

```
$ systemctl status | head -n 6

● destiny
    State: running
     Jobs: 0 queued
   Failed: 0 units
    Since: Tue 2019-01-22 17:33:01 MSK; 1min 29s ago
   CGroup: /

$ systemctl status systemd-resolved
● systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd-resolved.service(8)
           https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/resolved
           https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-network-configuration-managers
           https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-resolver-clients
```

Comment: Show me `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and `ps auxc | grep -i dns` and `host 8.8.8.8` and `host www.ebay.com`... all with VPN off. Edit this output as an edit to your question, not into the comments please. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: Thank you @heynnema for reaching out. I've updated my question with the requested info.

Comment: Thanks for the info. What version Ubuntu? Did this ever work, or is this a new problem? Your /etc/resolv.conf is a hard-wired file, not the symlink that it's supposed to be. Your OpenVPN script mods are also too old. Show me `ps auxc | grep -i resolv` and `cat /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` and `cat /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` and `ls -al /etc/openvpn`.

Comment: @heynnema I've updated the question.

Comment: Oh what a mess :-( Show me the first 5-6 lines from `systemctl status` and the entire `systemctl status systemd-resolved`. Uninstall `openresolv`. Remove any mods from the github link (probably mods to .ovpn files, and maybe a .sh script?).

Comment: @heynnema I've updated the question again. When I uninstall the `openresolv` the name servers from VPN connection is not getting propagated to the system configuration, but it's not fixing the initial problem after reboot. As I understand the `resolv.conf` should be a symlink to some other system file? But, even if I remove `openresolv` from the system, how do I make it work with VPN? Because that's what I was trying to do in the first place :)

Comment: Ah! systemd-resolved is disabled and dead. That's partially why it's not working. Let me try and put together a partial working answer to try and get things working for you. Do understand that in 18.xx, DNS is kinda broken, and it may take some more comments before we can get it 100%, so be patient, ok?

Comment: @heynnema Sure, I really appreciate your help, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note**: DNS is broken in 18.xx, with/without VPN.

---

**Problems...**

- your `/etc/resolv.conf` is a hard-wired file and should be a symlink
- your `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` and `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` are not getting populated
- you installed `openresolv`
- you followed a two-year-old script from github (*+ for trying though*)
- `systemd-resolved` is disabled and not running
- you're missing some required `network-manager` packages

---

**So... just to start...**

- uninstall `openresolv`
- remove all mods based on the github link
- re-enable and restart `systemd-resolved`

`sudo systemctl enable systemd-resolved` # re-enable systemd-resolved

`sudo systemctl start systemd-resolved` # start systemd-resolved

`sudo systemctl status systemd-resolved` # check the status

- recreate the `/etc/resolv.conf` symlink

`sudo rm -i /etc/resolv.conf` # remove the hard-wired file

<strike>`sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf` # recreate the symlink</strike>

`sudo ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf` # recreate the symlink

`reboot` # reboot the system

after reboot...

`cat /etc/resolv.conf` # check the contents of /etc/resolv.conf

and confirm that it contains something like 192.168.x.1 or the IP address of a upstream DNS server.

---

We'll modify your .ovpn scripts, import them to NetworkManager, and test VPN later. One thing to note is that using `sudo openvpn script_name.ovpn` may produce different results than importing the .ovpn file into NetworkManager.

**For your .ovpn files...**

Add the following at the end of the file (*try this with only one of your .ovpn files*).

```
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

then try...

`sudo openvpn script_name.ovpn` # connect via cli

`cat /etc/resolv.conf` # recheck the contents and confirm changes

`resolvectl` # check that DNS servers are getting assigned to tap0

Check for DNS leaks at http://dnsleak.com

---

**Update #1:**

I've changed my mind (*at least temporarily*) and have decided to change the symlink in the step "recreate the `/etc/resolv.conf` symlink"...

- recreate the `/etc/resolv.conf` symlink

`sudo rm -i /etc/resolv.conf` # remove the symlink

<strike>`sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf` # recreate the symlink</strike>

`sudo ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf` # recreate the symlink

- `resolvectl` may not show the expected result for device tap0 with VPN up

**Update #2:**

Now we'll import the modified .ovpn file into NetworkManager.

- open the `Network` settings panel
- locate the VPN section, and click the "+" icon to add a connection
- select `Import from file`
- locate your modified .ovpn and import it
- once imported, click the "ADD" button
- use the NetworkManager's VPN menu to connect to your VPN Server using the imported .ovpn
- check for DNS leaks at http://dnsleak.com
- `resolvectl` should show the expected result for device tap0 with VPN up

**Update #3:**

- installed missing packages...

`network-manager-openvpn`

`network-manager-openvpn-gnome`

`network-manager-vpnc`

- need to check for these (`dpkg -l *resolv* | grep ii`)...

`resolvconf`

`libnss-resolve`

**Update #4:**

<strike>Here's a screenshot of the "Wired Connection" NM script that I'm talking about... you can set DNS there (remember to set DNS AUTO to OFF, and then enter comma-separated DNS IP addresses)... or edit `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and edit the `#DNS=` line... however either of these might override the automatic handling of DNS with VPN that we're trying to get at 100%.</strike>

Remember that using `sudo openvpn client.ovpn` produces slightly different results than initiating a VPN connection from NetworkManager with an imported .ovpn script. In either case, you'll want to monitor the two resolv.conf that we have symlinked to `/etc/resolv.conf` and see which one appropriately shows the DNS servers from either your local network, or the VPN network, but normally not both... then adjust the symlink if required. (*note: we may have to also edit `/etc/nsswitch.conf`... more on that later*).

Remember that I said that DNS is kind of screwy in 18.xx :-) I finally got mine working pretty well, but it took some time.

[image]

---

**Update #5:**

Something to try... I have not played with this myself... so report back with your results.

Edit `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and temporarily comment out:

`hosts:  files myhostname mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns`

and put this in its place:

`hosts:  files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns myhostname`

**Update #6:**

If this is confusing... remember I said it might be...

Here's a test for you to run... take careful notes, as it's easy to get it wrong from memory... I know I did...

Let's just purely look at the output of `resolvectl`. There are 3 different places that we have to look to see if it's actually working right.

```
Global
       LLMNR setting: no
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
  Current DNS Server: 10.200.0.1 <--note
         DNS Servers: 10.200.0.1 <--note
```

and...

```
Link 5 (tun0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
  Current DNS Server: 10.200.0.1 <--note
         DNS Servers: 10.200.0.1 <--note
          DNS Domain: ~.
```

and...

```
Link 2 (eth0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.0.1 <--note
         DNS Servers: 192.168.0.1 <--note
          DNS Domain: ~
```

Run two separate tests...

Test #1...

- use the CLI, `sudo openvpn client.ovpn`
- note, using the above 3 examples, if your VPN DNS shows up anywhere
- go to `http://dnsleak.com` and check for a VPN IP and for DNS leaks

Test #2...

- use the NM interface to connect using your imported .ovpn file
- note, using the above 3 examples, if your VPN DNS shows up anywhere
- go to `http://dnsleak.com` and check for a VPN IP and for DNS leaks

Comment: Thank you once again. I've managed to restore the initial functionality of the DNS system, it now works after reboot. However, the `resolv.conf` file is not updated after establishing the VPN connection. Still, I see the following line in the connection log: `/etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf tap0 1500 1585 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 255.255.240.0 init`. But for some reason it's not getting propagated to the `resolv.conf`. The `resolvectl` also doesn't show DNS servers for `tap0` interface.

Comment: @SlavaFominII Progress! Good! What do you see in /etc/resolv.conf with and without VPN? Did you do the dns leak test with VPN up, and does it show a correct VPN IP address? You did ALL of the mods in my answer, yes? Now we can talk about using NetworkManager .ovpn imports and see if we can complete this job.

Comment: Actually, I'm not using VPN to access the Internet (I believe the DNS leak tool is for this use case, right?). I use VPN to access our corporate network. The `resolv.conf` file doesn't change after connecting to the VPN. It's the same as it was after reboot. What solution should I use to actually add DNS servers from the VPN? As I understand, the script on GitHub I was trying to use with openresolv is out of the question right? :)

Comment: @SlavaFominII I've added two updates in my answer.

Comment: Hello! I've tried to follow the updated instructions, but encountered some issues. The mentioned `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` file doesn't exist on my system. Also, there were no button to import ovpn-file in network manager. I've followed another guide and installed `network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome network-manager-vpnc` packages, so the button finally appeared. However, when trying to import the ovpn-file it errors with: `Key file contains "client" which is not a key-value pair, group, or comment`.

Comment: It looks like `Network-Manager is not able to automatically import OpenVPN config files with embedded certificates and keys`. I will try to extract them and will try again with import.

Comment: So, I've managed to extract all inline keys and certificates into external files and import the ovpn-file into network manager. Now I have a working connection. However, after connecting to VPN it created a new default route and routes all traffic to the VPN network, but, I want it to only route the specific resources. When I set the `Use this connection only for resources on its network` checkbox in connection settings (under IPv4 settings), the default route is gone and Internet is working, but DNS servers from VPN are no longer added to the `resolv.conf` file.

Comment: What could be done to remedy the situation? Ideally, I want Google DNS to be used for Internet resources resolving and VPN DNS for VPN resources resolving. Is it possible? Thank you!

Comment: @SlavaFominII This question keeps on morphing. NM should be able to import complete valid .ovpn files. "client" is a valid openvpn statement, but probably shouldn't be in a cert/key. Are your cert/keys human-readable? You did right by installing missing openvpn files. Earlier you said "I'm not using VPN to access the Internet. I use VPN to access our corporate network." If you put together the VPN DNS IP address along with Google DNS servers, you WILL have DNS leaks.

Comment: @SlavaFominII However, you can either try setting the NM connection script to IPV4->DNS AUTO OFF->ADD DNS servers IPs, or edit /etc/systemd/resolved.conf DNS= line. I don't know how to route SOME Internet traffic to Google DNS, and CORP traffic to corp DNS servers... unless you try something with routes, but I can't help with that. When VPN is up, it's supposed to keep ALL traffic in the secure tunnel, using only the VPN DNS server.

Comment: @SlavaFominII make sure that `resolvconf` and `libnss-resolve` are installed.

Comment: @SlavaFominII status please

Comment: Hello @heynnema! Thanks to you the connection is working great, but DNS servers from VPN are not propagated. I made sure that `resolvconf` and `libnss-resolve` are both installed, but it didn't help. Could you please explain to me this suggestion in more details please? -- `try setting the NM connection script to IPV4->DNS AUTO OFF->ADD DNS servers IPs` Thanks.

Comment: @SlavaFominII please see my Update #4. We're so close... check the symlinks first...

Comment: @SlavaFominII and Update #5...

Comment: I don't want to hardcode the DNS servers, because I want them to come from the VPN server (so they could be changed in the future by network administrators). However, even if I enter the DNS statically, it still not working. I also tried to update `nsswitch.conf` but without changes. By the way, is it enough to just re-enable the networking from the status bar or do I need to reboot the system for it to take effect?

Comment: Right now `/etc/resolv.conf` points to `../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` and contains `nameserver 127.0.0.53`. The `systemd-resolve --status` shows no DNS for the `tap0` interface. When I set the checkbox `Use this connection only for resources on its network` the DNS servers are not propagated for some reason. However, I want it only to not create the default gateway route.

Comment: @SlavaFominII I agree that hard-wiring DNS servers is not optimal. The temporary changes to /etc/nsswitch.conf probably require a reboot to stick. I've put up Update #6 for you to test while monitoring `resolvectl` instead of watching `/etc/resolv.conf`. Report back :-)

Comment: Initially, local DNS servers are configured for my primary network interface `eno1`. Other interfaces have no DNS. When I launch the tunnel using openvpn directly, VPN DNS servers are added to the global section of the `resolvectl`. Also, they are prepended to the `/etc/resolve.conf`. When I launch the tunnel using NM DNS configuration doesn't change at all.

Comment: @SlavaFominII It actually sounds like it's working... did you also do the http://dnsleak.com tests during both cli and NM trials?

Comment: It works when I run it manually via `sudo openvpn script.ovpn`, however, I would prefer to run it through NM considering that we went this way. But DNS configuration doesn't change when I connect to VPN through NM with `Use this connection only for resources on its network` flag enabled. Do you think it could be done?

Comment: @SlavaFominII I don't think that you want the `Use this connection only for resources on its network` flag enabled. Remember that I told you early on that dns is messed up in 18.xx, and that cli vs NM could act differently? Right now, I think the best we can do for you is to have it work via cli. I suspect that the .ovpn import into NM, with having to do the manual certs/keys extraction, didn't get imported correctly... as it should have imported the original file with certs/keys intact. I'd encourage you to continue playing with it, and keep me posted, if you like.

Comment: Thank you for all the help, I really appreciate it. I would definitely like to play with it further in order to fix the final gap, but I just lack the understanding of how the resolving system works in the current version of Ubuntu and how NM is supposed to communicate with it. And without this knowledge it would be a random guessing instead of a proper debugging. I think that all certificates and keys were extracted correctly, there is no problem here.

Comment: If I disable the `Use this connection only for resources on its network` then NM would create a default route, which will direct all my traffic to the VPN tunnel (and I don't want that). The only issue I have is with propagating DNS servers from the NM to the DNS system. Right now, I'm doing this manually and it works. If you know how I can make it propagate the DNS, but not to create the default route, this will really help me.

Comment: I would really like to mark your answer as an accepted one, but it will also mark my question as "solved", however, my problem is not yet fixed completely. This will send a wrong signal to the community. As soon as I would find an optimal way to tackle the last bits of this issue, I will be glad to close this question.

Comment: @SlavaFominII  I understand. We covered a lot of ground, and we got DNS working normally, and we got VPN working with CLI, but NM is still a problem. Report control support can be difficult, but if we've done everything that we've discussed, it should be working. As I mentioned, DNS is pretty busted in 18.xx, and I've had some luck getting it going for many folks, including myself, but VPN can throw an extra monkey wrench into the mix. Please let me know if you're able to solve it completely. Cheers!

Comment: @SlavaFominII small suggestion for you... your question title says "DNS not working after reboot", **which we solved**. I'd recommend starting a new question titled something like "VPN works via CLI, but not working with NetworkManager"